# MongoDB Schema Array Issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I update balance, I need to keep paymentCost and Date information as a Array. But I see only one payments info in everytime.

This is my user Model:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    balance: {
        type: Number,
        require: false,
    },
    payments: [{paymentCost: Number, paymentDate: Date}],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()

    }
})
```

and this is my update function:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: user._id }, 
            { $set: { "balance" : currentBalance, "payments":{"paymentDate": productCost, "paymentDate":date}}},

   async function (error, success) {
         if (error) {
            return callback({
                message: "Balance not updated"
            })
         } else {
            user = await User.findOne({email});
            return callback(null, {...user.toJSON()})
             console.log(success);
         }
     });
```

And I see every time below output:

[image]

Only one payments information keeps in time, how can I keep all of them in Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$set` is going to replace your current value instated of use `$set` you can try `$push` it will push your last object last on array and also if your want your last pushed object shoud be on first your can use the `$pop`

Comment: When I replace set with push I get this error:  message: "Balance not updated". I used like this         { $push: { "balance" : currentBalance, "payments":{"paymentDate": productCost, "paymentDate":date}}},

Comment: You can have to set your update query like that 
`your find query their
{
        $set: {
           your value
        },
        $push: {
            your pushed object their
           }
    }`

Comment: It works now thank you. I changed    as your suggestion     { $set: { "balance" : currentBalance},
        $push: { "payments" :  {"paymentDate": productCost, "paymentDate":date}}},

Answer (score 0):

With @Naim Biswas's help, my problem solved with below functions:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: user._id }, 
    { $set: { "balance" : currentBalance},
    $push: { "payments" :  {"paymentCost": productCost, "paymentDate":date}}},
   async function (error, success) {
         if (error) {
            return callback({
                message: "Balance not updated"
            })
         } else {
            user = await User.findOne({email});
            return callback(null, {...user.toJSON()})
             console.log(success);
         }
     });
```